# JQuery to check if textboxes are empty

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code which fills out all the date picker textboxes when a date is selected.

So there may be 5 date pickers.  Currently if the user selects a date in any of the date pickers, then ALL date pickers get populated with the selected date (so all 5 date pickers would have the same date)

```
    //populate all the  dates based on selected date
    $(".txtdatepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $(".txtdatepicker").val(dateText);
        }
    });
```

However, I want to change the code so that the selected date is only inserted into empty date pickers, i.e. the date picker does not already contain a value.

Would I use a .each for this?

EDIT:for some reason all my calendars are auto expanding, I have changed my code to this, is there any way to modify the following instead as it seesm to do the same as above?

```
$(".txtdatepicker").on("change", function(){

                     $(".txtdatepicker").val($(this).val());

             });
```

EDIT 2:

This is the solution used in the end:

```
$(".txtdatepicker").on("change", function(){ 
var date = $(this).val(); 
$(".txtdatepicker").each(function(){ 

if(!$(this).val()){ 
$(this).val(date); 

} 
}); 

});
```

Comment: your question is quite uncertain . Be clear in your words please .

Comment: While careful reading is involved it's clear what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".txtdatepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            $('.txtdatepicker').each(function(i,current){
                  if(!$(current).val()){ //empty string evaluates to false
                      $(current).val(dateText);
                }
            });               
    }
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/dnjrvdaq/3/

Comment: this doesn't seem to work.  I want to insert into every date picker that is empty (does not have a value)

Comment: check the edit...now we are checking every datefield...and inserting date only in empty fields..

Comment: this code still changes all the date pickers, even if they have a value

Comment: check now....i have not used trim here because jquery datepicker doesnt allow any text to be entered..

Comment: for some reason this causes all the datepicker calendars to expand automatically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61425/discussion-between-bhavya-w-and-user3437721).

Answer (score 2):

You were close.

```
$(".txtdatepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        $(".txtdatepicker").each(function(){ // each - you were right!
            if( !$.trim( $(this).val() ).length ) 
            // check if the trimmed value is not 0
                $(this).val(dateText);
        });
    }
});
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/8249zoxr/

Comment: Remember to upvote and accept it this answers your question. @user3437721

Comment: for some reason this causes all the datepicker calendars to expand automatically?

Comment: Not for me. Given the JavaScript this is the solution.